# Booting a file-copied Linux root partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, backup

I created a file backup of my root partition using duplicity, with the following command:

```
duplicity \
   -v8 \
   --no-encryption \
   --exclude-other-filesystems \
   --exclude-device-files \
   --exclude /lost+found \
   --exclude '/tmp/*' \
   / \
   file:///.../root-backup/ \
| tee -a /.../backup.log
```

Then I restored this backup to a second partition on the same hard drive, intending to install a dist upgrade on that version of the system while leaving the original alone.

Unfortunately, I can't boot that second partition.

I've already taken care of the most obvious stuff: Creating directories `/dev`, `/sys` and `/proc` which were skipped by the backup, and modifying the cloned `/etc/fstab` to mount the new partition as `/`.

Now I tried to boot this partition simply by entering the grub console and typing

```
set root=(hd0,msdos2)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-[kernel version here]
initrd /boot/initrd.img-[kernel version]
boot
```

This results in a kernel panic, with an error along the lines of:

```
/init: can't open /root/dev/console: no such file
kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!
```

What else do I need to do on the new partition in order to be able to use it as `/`?